# xrandr not respecting '--primary' or '--left{right}-of'

Tags: x11, xrandr, bspwm

I have the following in my .xinitrc:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --off
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off

# set monitors
if [ xrandr -q | grep 'HDMI-1 connected' | wc -l == 1 ] ; then
    xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary --mode 2560x1080
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 2560x1440 --right-of HDMI-1
else
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440
fi
```

The output of `xrandr -q | grep 'HDMI-1 connected' | wc -l` is 1 when HDMI-1 is plugged in. Both monitors work fine, but HDMI-1 is not primary and eDP-1 is. In addition if I switch the `--right-of` to `--left-of` I see no difference. It looks to me like there's something else setting the monitors. Removing these lines however disables HDMI-1 so I'm not sure what's going on.

A bit of system info:
I'm using a lenovo laptop with bspwm and lightdm. If you need more info please let me know.

EDIT:
Just putting the lines

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary --mode 2560x1080
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 2560x1440 --right-of HDMI-1
```

into my .xinitrc without the conditional doesn't work either.

Comment: I suspect you want `if [ "$(xrandr -q | grep 'HDMI-1 connected' | wc -l)" -eq 1 ] ; then`

Comment: Thanks! My bash scripting isn't the best. However I tried this and get the same functionality (or lack of) still.

Comment: Also, setting `--primary` after launch works just fine...